# Python 2.7.3 errno 13 opening 777 permission file using effective uid

Tags: python, file-permissions, errno

I have a file that has 777 permissions in Linux inside a directory that is 2770.  As root, I am starting Python interactively and trying to set the effective UID to a user without root privs (my regular user account, UID 1010) to access the file, but I am getting Errno 13

OS: Linux (RHEL6U3)
Python: 2.7.3
Parent Directory permissions: 2770 (root owned, user UID is in group)
File Permissions: 777 (-rwxrwxrwx)

The root parent dir:

```
[root@server / ]#  ls -AFlhd test
64K drwxrwxrwx  4 root FSTEST    2.1K Feb 14 20:42 test/
```

The parent dir:

```
[root@server /test ]#  ls -AFlhd t1
64K drwxrws---  4 root FSTEST    2.1K Feb 14 20:42 t1/
```

The file:

```
[root@server /test/t1]#  ls -AFlh 06.dd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root             1.0G Feb 14 19:34 06.dd*
```

How to produce the problem:

```
[root@server /test/t1]#  python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2013, 16:23:20) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> print(os.getresuid(),os.getresgid())
((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))

>>> os.stat("06.dd")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33279, st_ino=1064458, st_dev=64513L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=1073741824, st_atime=1360875706, st_mtime=1360870449, st_ctime=1360875600)

>>> fp = open("06.dd")
>>> fp.close()
>>> os.seteuid(1010)
>>> print(os.getresuid(),os.getresgid())
((0, 1010, 0), (0, 0, 0))

>>> fp = open("06.dd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '06.dd'
```

So here's the unusual part ... if I change the permissions of the parent directory to 777, the `fp=open("06.dd")` works with `os.seteuid(1010)`!

And the even stranger part:  If I su to my user and run Python interactively that way, it also works just fine without having to set the file to 777!

```
[root@server /test/t1]#  su - user ; cd /test/t1/
[user@server /test/t1 ]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2013, 16:23:20) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getresuid(),os.getresgid())
((1010, 1010, 1010), (1000, 1000, 1000))

>>> os.stat("06.dd")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33279, st_ino=1064458, st_dev=64513L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=1073741824, st_atime=1360875706, st_mtime=1360870449, st_ctime=1360875600)

>>> fp = open("06.dd")
>>> fp.close()
```

What's going on?  I'm thoroughly confused at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the owner of `t1`, so the owner permissions do not apply to you.

In the first case, your effective group is not the `FSTEST` group, so the group permissions do not apply to you either. In the second case, your effective group is the `FSTEST` group, because su is clever enough to set your effective group as well as your effective user (they are separate system calls). Try using

```
os.setegid(1000)
os.seteuid(1010)
fp = open("06.dd")
```

Comment: It was definitely a group permissions issue ... instead of just using setegid, however, I'm going to do a os.setgroups([]) so that all groups that the user belongs to is included.  This is the default behaviour for su.

Thanks!